# What to use in order to have full consolidated table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I am creating two tables .

Table 1 has following schema

```
user_id       int            not null,autoincrement
movie _id     int            not null 
movie_name    varchar        
user_name     varchar
rating        int
genre         varchar
```

while table 2 has following schema

```
movie _id     int            not null 
movie_name    varchar        
user_name     varchar
genre         varchar
rating        varchar
```

Now when I put a query to insert values it first checks whether a following username exist in first table .If true then it inserts into second table otherwise it inserts value as per schema into first table.In other words first table has unique usernames and unique user_Id while second contains many repeated usernames with movie they have seen

So there are following values which I am inserting via form(Java ,servlet) into my tables

```
user_Id    movie_Id    movie_name      user_name   rating  genre
1           1           Twister         Alex          6      Drama
2           1           Twister         Tim           1      Drama
3           2           sweet november  pam           5      Romantic
4           3           The pianist     carl          5      Drama 
5           4           narnia          stephen       7      Fantasy   
..
..
(contd..)
```

Table 2

```
    movie_Id   movie_Name    user_name     genre     Rating
    2          sweet november  Alex        Romantic    4
    3          The pianist     Alex        Drama       5
    4          narnia          Pam         Fantasy     8
    9          maceth          Tim         Drama       9
    ..
    ....

(contd.)
```

..
.Further I want to merge both the tables so that it gives me the following image

```
user_id   movie_Id  movie_name      user_name   rating  genre
1         1         Twister            Alex        6      Drama
1         2         sweet november     Alex        4      Romantic
1         3         The pianist        Alex        5      Drama
2         1         Twister            Tim         1      Drama
2         9         macbeth            Tim         9      Drama
3         2         Sweet November     Pam         5      Romatic
3         4         Narnia             Pam         8      Fantasy
4         3         The Pianist        Carl        5      Drama
5         4         Narnia             Stephen     7      Fantasy
... and so on 

What should I use
```

I tried with join but it neglects first table value.I want to have both table values just after i enter values in form and then i click

This is following syntax which i was using

```
select * from table2 inner join table1 on table2.user_name = table1.user_name
```

Please suggest something

Thanks

Comment: Your table structure is hard to understand.  What are `table1` and `table2` supposed to represent?  Aside from the superfluous `user_id` tag, the only field that's not on both is `Rating`

Comment: Hi Doug M yes you are correct but the only thing which I am trying to achieve is to make a consolidated table joining or merging both tables

Comment: Hi Eggyal,Yeah you are true ,I still cannot get the desired result

Comment: You're only getting results from table2 with `INNER JOIN` as it will only show results in table1 which have a username matching in table2. You want a `UNION` if you want to select all data from both tables in 1 query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a really bad data design.  For instance, there is no obvious link from table2 to table1.  It should have a `user_id` column rather than `user_name`.

The answer to your question, though, is `union all` rather than a `join` (or, rather, in addition to).  You need a join to look up the `user_id` for the second table:

```
select user_id, movie_Id, movie_name, user_name, rating, genre
from Table1 union all
select t1.user_id, t2.movie_Id, t2.movie_name, t2.user_name,  t2.rating, t2.genre
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t2.user_name = t1.user_name;
```

That said, you should revise your database structure.  As a hint, it should have three tables:  `users`, `movies`, and `user_movies`.